# Passing a variable into SQL statement with rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass the variable `supplier` into the where clause of my sql statement. It saves the variable as when i click the link it shows the chosen supplier in the `url`. I just have no idea what to put in the statement to make it pick up the variable from the view.

Model:

```
def self.find_supplier
find_by_sql(["SELECT s.supplier, s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
WHERE s.supplier = ? AND l.amount > 0
GROUP BY s.supplier, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition", :supplier)
end
```

View:

```
<% @softwares.each do |l| %>
<li>
<%= link_to "#{l.supplier}", :controller =>'softwares', :action => 'export_supplier', :supplier => l.supplier %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def export_supplier
@software = Software.find_supplier
software = CSV.generate do |csv|

# for the headers of the csv file
  csv << ["Quantity", "Item Number", "Item Description"]
  # the chosen rows from the database
  @software.each do |s|
    csv << [s.amount, s.productcode, s.description, s.supplier]
  end
end
send_data(software, :type => 'text/csv', :filename => 'software.csv')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find_by_sql(["SELECT s.supplier, s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
```

FROM softwares s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
WHERE s.supplier = ? AND l.amount > 0
GROUP BY s.supplier, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition", params[:supplier])

I assume the find_by_sql is in your controllers, "export_supplier" method. 
Here you should get params[:supplier]

Comment: I've updated my question with the code in my controller, I've added what you said and i get this error `undefined local variable or method 'params'`

Comment: The params are not accessible in the model, you have to pass it to the model as a paramter Software.find_supplier(params[:supplier])  

and in the model def self.find_supplier(supplier) ....... end

Comment: then you will have a supplier variavle in model, and not :supplier

I would suggest go through some good rails book first like the rails 3 way by Obie